# Facebook Open Graph Activity shows blank captions and taller thumbnail image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a facebook application that posts to the users Open Graph whenever they beat a level. It posts the score and other information about how they beat the level.

I use the activity feed to look at these open graph posts. I am running into an issue where for one user their activities don't show the captions and the image is bigger.

Screenshot of messed up Activity: [image: Screenshot of messed up Activity]
<sub>(source: [stiqjoy.com](http://stiqjoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ActivityBlank.png))</sub>

Screenshot of correct Activity: [image: Screenshot of correct Activity]
<sub>(source: [stiqjoy.com](http://stiqjoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ActivityCorrect.png))</sub>

These activities were appearing correctly for the given user, but have recently started not appearing corretly.

I'm a bit stumped as to what the problem could be. I have been playing with the "beat" action and changing some of the captions. I have also changed the Action's properties from time to time. Also, I am giving the open graph post a thumbnail image that is 200x200, instead of the 90x90 that it displays in the Activity feed.

It seems that once this problem starts occurring for a user, it continues to be a problem for every open graph post of that action type that I make for that user.

The weirdest thing is that it continues to work fine for user A, and continues to be broken for user B. It is like something gets messed up for that specific user, and then stays messed up for them.

I'm open to any ideas, and would appreciate any help you can give me.

**Edit**

I just found it occurring with the "like" action. Except this time, one Activity is wrong and the next activity is right (Both for the same action on different objects) I've looked over both requests in open graph and there is literally no differences, except for the name of the level and object url. I looked at the meta for the object urls and there isn't anything different except for the names of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set user_generated to false, explicitly, on the image. Also make sure both your og:description and og:title fields are set.

Here is a little more on user_generated images:

[iOS - Facebook Open Graph Api -- ensuring that photos are user generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538712/ios-facebook-open-graph-api-ensuring-that-photos-are-user-generated)

Please check out the links in the question above:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/adding-photos-to-stories/

Comment: in fact, I am having the opposite problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623341/ios-facebook-open-graph-api-getting-captions-to-show-up-next-to-user-genera