# iOS - Facebook Open Graph API -- Getting captions to show up next to user generated images

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cannot get a caption to show up on a user-generated photo, like so:

[image]

Instead, this is a non-user generated photo,with a title and description:

[image]

after enabling user-generated photos (via [iOS - Facebook Open Graph Api -- ensuring that photos are user generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538712/ios-facebook-open-graph-api-ensuring-that-photos-are-user-generated) ), it looks like this:

[image]

note- on the image above, both title and description are set just as in the first image. However, the description does not show up. The title, on the other hand, does.

After setting the title to empty, this is the result:

[image]

Open graph object on the web is like so:

```
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['fb:app_id']);?>">
  <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo strip_tags(curPageURL());?>">
  <meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:type']);?>">
  <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:title']);?>">
  <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:description']);?>">
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:image']);?>">
  <meta property="fb:explicitly_shared" content="true">
```

What do I need to do in order to get the caption to show up alongside having a user_generated, full size image?
Maybe something is configured incorrectly on facebook? Meal is a predefined object defined by facebook. Should I try using another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a caption, it's a user message.

You need to set the `message` in your code and in settings as a field as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/

[image: Message field]

> Allows users to write a personalized message attached to this action. You can only use this when the text is entered by the user and not pre-populated. You can mention users and pages inline using mention tagging.

Furthermore, in iOS code (objective-c) from this tutorial 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/:

In this method:

```
- (void)postOpenGraphActionWithPhotoURL
```

setting this property:

```
action.message = @"your message here";
```

gives the desired result.